# Why is the <form> not getting right aligned inside <nav>?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert my search bar inside the `<nav>` tag of my HTML web page. It's basically a text-box of an HTML `<form>` that I want to be right aligned while the other menu items should bear default alignment *(the other menu items being plain text as `<h2>` heading with links)*.

This is the `<nav>` bar of my page (the page is a .PHP page):

```
<nav>
    <!--site navigation links-->

    <h2 style="display:inline-block;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.html" style="color:#ffdd77;">
    Home.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="about.html">About.</a></h2>

    <!--search bar-->

    <form align="right" action="search.php" method="GET" 
     style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="keyword search" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

</nav>
```

The problem is that the `<form>` is not getting right aligned. The output is as shown in the image below:

[image]

I also tried setting the `align` attribute of the `<input/>` tags to `"right"` but it still didn't help. I am able to shift it to the right end by putting a number of blank spaces (`&nbsp;` - about 90 of them) in between the navigation links and the form but isn't there a way I could do it with any HTML/CSS attribute/parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET" 
     style="display:inline-block;float:right!important;margin-top:25px;">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="keyword search" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

That should work.

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obrtfsdo/)

Comment: That was a quick response. Thanks :-)

Comment: Absolutey. That's why were here.

Answer (score 2):

Try using float.
Align is for text

```
<h2 style="display:inline-block;">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.html" style="color:#ffdd77;">
Home.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="about.html">About.</a></h2>

<!--search bar-->

<form style="float:right"  action="search.php" method="GET" 
 style="display:inline-block;">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="keyword search" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
form {
  position: absolute;
    right:0px;
  }
```

```css
form {
  position: absolute;
right:0px;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
    <!--site navigation links-->

    <h2 style="display:inline-block;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.html" style="color:#ffdd77;">
    Home.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="about.html">About.</a></h2>

    <!--search bar-->

    <form align="right" action="search.php" method="GET" 
     style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="keyword search" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

</nav>
```

or

```
form {
  float:right;
  }
```

```css
form {
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
    <!--site navigation links-->

    <h2 style="display:inline-block;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.html" style="color:#ffdd77;">
    Home.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="about.html">About.</a></h2>

    <!--search bar-->

    <form align="right" action="search.php" method="GET" 
     style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="keyword search" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do this using a grid system. For example using the [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could look at the [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) display.

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

**Html code**

```
<nav>
    <h2 >
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.html" style="color:#ffdd77;">
    Home.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="about.html">About.</a></h2>

    <!--search bar-->

    <form align="right" action="search.php" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="keyword search" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

    </nav>
```

**Add Css**

```
   nav{
     display: flex;
   }
   form{
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-left: 10px;
   }
```